# something about JOptionPane.showInputDialog in java

Tags: java, if-statement

i'm new in java and have a phase of code like this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class test
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String value=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please input your value");
  if (value== "1"){
   System.out.println("1");
  }else{
   System.out.println("not 1");
   }
  }
}
```

Question : why every time i put 1,system print "not 1"?

thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing value == "1" with value.equals("1").  Strings in Java are references and there are no operator overloads to help you with equality.  Sometimes the strings are interned and == would work, but not usually.  You should always use the equals method.